# How can I add an autocorrect mapping to the iOS dictionary?

Tags: ios, dictionary, autocorrect

My iPhone, running iOS 6, used to autocorrect `ill` -> `I'll` for me and I liked that. It has, very recently, stopped doing this. I suppose it makes sense given than `ill` is actually a word, but it is a word I rarely use and certainly use far less frequently than `I'll`.

Is there any way to add a correction mapping back to the iOS 6 dictionary such that typing `ill` autocorrects to `I'll` for me?

Comment: I noticed this too a few weeks ago, on an iPhone which is still running iOS 5.

Answer (score 6):

My workaround has been to add a keyboard shortcut that replaces the text `ill` with `I'll` any time I add it. Not perfect, but as a stop-gap it will do.

To add the shortcut go to Settings -> General -> Keyboard and scroll to the bottom of the page. You will see an `Add New Shortcut...` button. Press it.

[image]

In the Shortcut configuration page type `I'll` in to the Phrase entry box and `ill` in to the Shortcut entry box and press the `Save` button.

[image]

Now any time you type `ill` it will auto-correct to `I'll`.

Comment: Somehow my iPhone started autocorrecting "thr" to "Thr". This shortcut workaround solved that problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's an imperfect solution, but there's always the option of resetting the Keyboard Dictionary. This undoes all the learning your iPhone has done, so you're back to the fresh-out-of-the-box behaviour. Obviously this may be a set-back in some areas, but if you're getting strange behaviour, it may be the way to go.

To reset the learning, open **Settings → General → Reset** and tap **Reset Keyboard Dictionary**.

Comment: This is overkill.